# Finding the equation of a plane

Tags: geometry

I need to find the equation for the plane which goes through the intersection line of the planes $x-z=1$ and $y+2z=3$, and perpendicular to the plane $x+y-2z=1$.

What I got so far - to find the intersection line I looked at $x-z = 1$ and $y+2x=5$, so I chose $z=0$ and I got a point $P_{1}$(1, 3, 0), which is on the intersection line.

Now I tried to express the plane equation using a point and a normal - I used $P_1$ as the point and $n_3 =<1, 1, -2>$ as the normal, so I got -

$x +y -2z = 4$, as the required plane.

Am I correct?

Thanks.

Comment: Your equation defines a plane parallel to $x+y-2z=1$. Not perpendicular.

Comment: Both *your plane* and he one it is supposed to be perpendicular to have the same direction vector $\,(1,1,-2)\,$...what do you think of that?

Comment: What if I used $n_3 = <1,1,-1>$ instead?

Comment: It should be $n_3=<1,1,1>$. Here is a [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/281215/find-an-equation-of-the-plane).

Comment: How did you come up with $\,n_3\,$ , @homiee ? It is correct, BTW.(hint: inner product...)

Comment: I searched for a vector $n_3$ which gives $n_3\cdot<1,1,-2>=0$

Comment: @homiee: Notice that, I already gave a general technique for how to find such a vector formally in the link I referred you to it.

Comment: Thanks alot for your comments everyone