# provide a formula in terms of x and y for all unit vectors that are orthognal to (x, y)

Tags: vector-spaces

Hi I have an HW question:

> Given any vector $(x,y) in R$, provide a formula in terms of $x$ and $y$ for all unit vectors that are orthogonal to $(x, y)$

**My answer is:**
Let any unit vector be defined as $(a,b)$ which should satisfy the following equation 
$ax+by=0$
for it to be orthogonal to $(x, y)$

That seemed a bit too easy which raises my doubt on whether i understood the question correctly or not. So did I? Did I answer is correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Geometrically, if you have a vector $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$, what do vectors orthogonal to it look like? Can you find a formula for one such vector? (That is, can you think of one solution for $a$ and $b$ in your equation?)

If you can, then you have found one vector orthogonal to $(x,y)$. Now you presumably know how to turn that into a unit vector. Can you also figure out how to find the other unit vector that is orthogonal once you have the first one?

Answer (score 0):

Now, you need to solve the equation you have got for $a$ and $b$. Since you have one eq. in two 
Variables, then you will have one free  variable, say $b=t$. Subs back in the eq. To find $a$ and you are done. See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/281215/find-an-equation-of-the-plane).

Comment: Why would you refer to your solution which is incorrect?