# Equation of a plane given two lines

Tags: calculus

Find the equation of a plane that contains both r and s.

Let r be $x=3t, y=-t+1,z=t$ and $x=3t, y=-t+1,z=t-2$,

So far I found the cross product and it gave me $(3t-2)\hat{i}-6t\hat{j}.$

What do I do from here?

Comment: You can find answer from almost same question here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209579/find-the-equation-of-the-plane-that-contains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lines are $${\bf l_1}(t)=t(3,-1,1)+(0,1,0)$$  $${\bf l_2}(t)=t(3,-1,1)+(0,1,-2)$$

These are parallel lines through different points. Thus, you may first find a vector $\bf  v$ which starts at the first and ends at the second, and then take the cross product of this $\bf v$ with your direction ${\bf w}=(3,-1,1)$ to obtain a normal vector to the plane you seek.

Make a drawing if you cannot visualize what is going on, it usually helps.